std::array - How can I create a fixed size class member of an object that can't get default constructed
I'm building a container class for any type T that needs to keep a list of T that has length known at compile time. I'm struggling to find a data structure that can work well for this problem, as std::array complains when I try to initialize my object in the body of my constructor. Critically, the type T is not default constructible.
Here is a snippet that about corresponds to the functionality that I am looking for
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

struct not_default_constructible
{
    not_default_constructible(int){}
};

static_assert(!std::is_default_constructible_v<not_default_constructible>);

/*
Does not compile!
*/

template<typename T, long N>
struct array_of_ndc
{
    std::array<T,N> arr;

    array_of_ndc(T init)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = init;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    array_of_ndc<not_default_constructible, 2> ndc(not_default_constructible{2});
}

The trouble with this snippet (which does not compile!) is that the compiler wants me to initialize my std::array before the body of my constructor.
Here is one solution I wrote, but it very much feels like I'm fighting with the compiler with this (and it breaks everything I love about std::array, i.e. iterators), and I wanted to see if there is a more STL friendly solution to this.
template<typename T, long N>
struct no_construction_arr
{
    alignas(T) char data[N * sizeof(T)];

    template<typename U>
        requires(std::constructible_from<T,U>)
    no_construction_arr(U&& init)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            new (&data[i * sizeof(T)]) T (init);
        }
    }

    T* operator[](size_t index)
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[index * sizeof(T)]);
    }

    ~no_construction_arr()
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            (reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[i * sizeof(T)]))->~T();
        }
    }
};

I'll also add that, I know I can do this with std::vector. This is about trying to take advantage of the fact that I know the size of the list that I will need ahead of time, and so it seems wasteful to make an unneeded dynamic allocation.

Have you been exposed to the member initialiizer List? You do the initialization there. All you can do in the body of the constructor is assignment because the members are all initialized by that point. If the initialization logic is complicated, you make a helper function that you can call from the member initializer list.

@273K int can be default constructed, so your snippet will compile. My original snippet, with not_default_constructible, will not.
https://godbolt.org/z/G4Kjc4d8z

@user4581301 sure, thanks for the suggestion. I added in the title and body that T may not be default constructible. So the issue with doing this in the member initializer list is that I just outsource the problem : now I need a function that can instantiate a std::array<T,N> without initializing the values (hence my issue).

Yeah, now that I understand your problem, you're no better off. Still have to jump through the sorts of hoops outlined in the answer below, and the answer does the job more elegantly than what had in mind.

To get a sequence or repetition where you don't already have a parameter pack to expand, use std::make_index_sequence:
#include <utility>
#include <array>

struct not_default_constructible
{
    not_default_constructible(int){}
};

template<typename T, unsigned long N>
struct array_of_ndc
{
public:
    std::array<T,N> arr;

    explicit array_of_ndc(const T& init)
      : array_of_ndc(init, std::make_index_sequence<N>{})
    {}

private:
    template <std::size_t ...I>
    explicit array_of_ndc(const T& init, std::index_sequence<I...>)
      : arr{ { (static_cast<void>(I), init)... } }
    {}
};


Great - exactly what I was looking for. Another question about this - is this approach of a "public facing" constructor calling a more mechanical private facing constructor a common pattern? I haven't seen it before but it is impressively useful here...

Not sure how common. Delegating constructors can be useful for a number of reasons, but the target constructor is often also public.
